# Error while passing multiple files from different directories to for loop

Tags: for-loop, unix

Could you guys check the below message and provide me any solution or hint to resolve issue with for loop variable.

The files which i have in below format:

```
/directory/file1.gz -> gunzip file1, it will be in ascll format
/directory/file2.gz -> gunzip file2, but the file2 still in gzip format
```

For clearing this issue, I have written below small script:

```
for f in ./ETF_Directories_*/*;
do
if file -z "$f" | grep -i ascii
then
echo "file is in ascii format"
else
gunzip "$f"
//**If the file is not in ascii format I mean the second case I want to 
move this gunziped file to .gz. So that it will in single .gz format, but 
I need command to write, or hint on how to use "mv" command to achieve 
what I needed**//
fi
done
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Your requirement is not clear.

Comment: if the file format is not ascii as in else statement:
I want to gunzip the file and use mv command to make a perfect ascii zip file.
Like this:-
`gunzip "$f"`
`mv "$f" "$f.gz"`
But, it is trowing me error that the mv cant find the file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

`gunzip x.gz` will remove `.gz`, so when `$f` is `something.gz`, the extension is lost and `$f` can not be found.

Comment: Yes , that’s where I stuck... I need to perform other commands on that gunziped file .... how can I do that ..... can I move it to other variable ???

Comment: You want to remove `.gz` when present. Use `"${f%.gz}"`, test with `f="no_dot_gz"`,  `f="one.gz"` and `f="two.gz.gz"`.